# How to write a path with LaTeX?

Tags: windows, latex

How can I write a path with LaTeX? I want something like this:

```
C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\my file.txt
```

I **have** to use double slashes, not single ones.

Comment: Did you try using double-double slashes:

    `C:\\\\Program Files\\\\My Program\\\\my file.txt`?

Comment: I tried that but it's adding 2 new lines

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.

Comment: A path should not be set as normal text, but as verbatim, e.g. `\verb|C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\my file.txt|`. This will also prevent errors from special characters which might be in the path like underscores etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this:

[How does one insert a backslash or a tilde into Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-)

> The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List is your friend. \textbackslash and \textasciitilde are found in Table 2 of the list

So you should try

```
C:\textbackslash\textbackslash Program Files\textbackslash\textbackslash My Program\textbackslash\textbackslash my file.txt
```

Comment: Note that `\` terminates a macro, so you don't need the space in consecutive `\foo\foo`.

Comment: @Joey hey, for all this work, you'd at least deserve a +1...